# How to display validation errors inline instead of at the top of page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, inline, omniauth

I am trying to get my user model validation errors to display inline with its corresponding form field. I am using bootstrap and devise. I have client side validations so it wont let you submit the signup form until most of the validations are met. The problem is when a user signs up with facebook via omniauth. Omniauth will take the fields that facebook gives me and use those for the user, but the fields that facebook does not offer  will then raise an ugly looking error on the top of the page. I have been trying to find a way to get those to display inline.

This is my user Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :bills, :dependent => :destroy

    validates :cell_phone, presence: true
    validates :cell_phone, length: { is: 10 }
    validates :cell_phone, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :terms, presence: true

    geocoded_by :last_sign_in_ip
    after_validation :geocode


    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable



    def ability
    @ability ||= Ability.new(self)
    end

    delegate :can?, :cannot?, :to => :ability



    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(auth.slice(:sprovider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
            user.sprovider = auth.provider
            user.uid = auth.uid
            user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
            user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.cell_phone = auth.info.cell_phone
            user.avatar = auth.info.image
        end
    end
```

This is the devise signup form that i would like the inline errors to appear on:

```
<div class="row sign_in">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">


    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6">  
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true , class:'form-control',placeholder:'First Name *' , :required => true %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, class:'form-control',placeholder:'Last Name*' , :required => true %>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.phone_field :cell_phone, class:'form-control',placeholder:'Mobile Number*(Solely for notification purposes)', :required => true, :maximum => 10, :minimum => 10 %>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.email_field :email, class:'form-control',placeholder:'Email*', :required => true %>
  </div>

  <% if f.object.password_required? %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <% if @validatable %><i></i><% end %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class:'form-control',placeholder:'Password* (8 characters minimum)', id:"myPassword", :required => true %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class:'form-control',placeholder:'Password Confirmation*', :required => true %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.check_box :terms%>
    I have read and agreed the User

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Terms and Conditions</a>
         <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pretium libero eget posuere ornare. Donec rutrum augue eu erat fringilla posuere. Aenean tempus dui a erat facilisis posuere. Pellentesque eget nulla et turpis mollis egestas. Donec molestie consequat ultricies. Vivamus in feugiat risus. Ut a quam id sapien fringilla efficitur eget in justo. Suspendisse tincidunt libero metus. Sed ultrices auctor diam mattis pretium. Integer in aliquam dui. Praesent pulvinar ante non urna consectetur, eget porta lorem porta. Etiam ac orci pretium, faucibus neque vel, egestas velit. Nullam condimentum ultrices imperdiet. Maecenas vel nisi commodo, bibendum purus dapibus, porttitor felis.

Nullam nec porta lectus. Vivamus porta lobortis justo, sed cursus arcu tincidunt et. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque a rhoncus tellus. Ut mollis orci quis lacus consequat, quis varius nunc auctor. Ut elit ligula, bibendum quis mauris a, ornare elementum dui. Phasellus commodo ipsum eu augue consequat porta.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

  <div><i class="icon-heart"></i></div>
    <%= f.submit 'Sign up', class:'btn btn-primary btn-block' %> 

      <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the sign in with facebook button:

```
<div><i class="icon-heart"></i></div>
    <%= f.submit 'Sign in', class:'btn btn-primary btn-block' %> 
    <%= link_to "Sign in with facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), class:'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
    <br>
    <div align="center"> 
</div>
```

Any help on how to go about displaying these validation errors are much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to add conditions to validations, i.e. not validate some of the attributes when the facebook id is present (meaning user is signing up form facebook)

```
validates :first_name, presence: true, if: Proc.new {|u| u.facebookid.nil? }
```

Regarding the errors in your form, you can get rid of the top section that displays all the errors, and use

```
<%= user.errors[:first_name] %>
```

close to your field instead. You can always get access to attribute (form field) errors by doing

```
object.errors[:attributename]
```

Comment: Not sure I get what you're asking, but the suggestion was only because you asked to display the specific field error close to your input element.

Answer (score 3):

We've achieved this before here: http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk (click "Register")

The way we did it was actually quite simple:

---

**Errors**

Every error you would display from the model will have to be defined in the `@object.errors` hash.

Instead of displaying the errors on the top of your page, you'll actually be able to manually cycle through the hash, and display the errors & display them on the form *in line*:

```
#app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
<%= form_for ........ do |f| %>
   <%= f.email_field :email %>
   <%= devise_resource.errors[:email].first if devise_resource.errors[:email].present? %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously a much simplified example, but as you can see, you'll be able to display the error inline with the input if it's present. This code is somewhat old (might not be `devise_resource` any more) - either way, we've found the best way is to just show the errors where you'd like as above

Comment: Hi Rich, Thanks for your quick response. How can i define errors in the @object.errors hash?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `simple_form_for` instead of `form_for` if you use the Simple Form gem.
`simple_form_for` will show error message inline automatically.

Gem [read me here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

If you want to show full error message then follow this link [Display inline errors with simple_form in a Bootstrap Ajax modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408508/display-inline-errors-with-simple-form-in-a-bootstrap-ajax-modal). Hope this helps you!