# Bootstrap Modal window doesn't render model validation errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a basic modal window on my home page that renders a form to create a new `Post`.

I have a length validation in the `Post` model and want the form to display an error if it doesn't meet the minimum length.

This is the Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, length: { in: 1..400 }
end
```

And this is my `home.html.erb` view

```
<!-- Modal button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#tweetModal">
  New Tweet
</button>


<!-- Tweet Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="tweetModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="tweetModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="tweetModalLabel">Send a new Tweet</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">X</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <%= simple_form_for @post, remote: true do |f| %>
          <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.input :content %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
          </div>
        <% end %>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = @user
    if @post.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
  end

  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

The modal window won't render the error and the only way I've found to render it is to `render :new` if the  `Post` could not be saved.

The problem with that is that it will render the `new.html.erb` view that belongs to Post instead of the modal window that I have in my home page.

Can I make the modal window display the error? Should I move the modal window code to a separate partial file and use JS to render it?

Comment: I would recommend exactly as you suggested. Move the form to a partial render the partial and then you should be able to rerender the partial and replace the modal content on failure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051050/ajax-form-using-simple-form-with-preserved-error-validation/10054583 seems like a good fit

Comment: @engineersmnky  Thanks. How do you make JS render a partial file?